# Unique list on MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of companies in MongoDB, like this

```
{
   "ID" : "123456",
   "NAME" : "10GEN"
}
```

I want an atomic operation to insert a new company document if the company name is unique, else report back that the insert failed.  Not sure how to do this with the official Mongo c# driver?

One approach is to define a unique index and execute a regular insert in a try/catch, but this is using exception handling to control flow.  What I am hoping for is a composite command, like FindAndModify.

Comment: It’s still not clear what your flow is. What do you want to do in case there is an existing document?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [unique index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique%3Atrue) on `NAME`.

Comment: This is one solution. In fact, the collection definitely requires an index. However, for the given scenario it relies on exception handling which is less than ideal.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You asked for a solution that would “report back that the insert failed”, which is sort of an exception. A unique index does just that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I have edited my question to be more specific.  Thanks

Comment: It’s still not clear what your flow is. What do you want to do in case there *is* an existing document?